# How to change example.com/blog.html to example.com/blog

Tags: html, web, url

[**www.tinynerdgames.com/blog.html**](http://www.tinynerdgames.com/blog.html)

---

I want this page's URL to not end with /blog.html rather with /blog. So the wished end result would be: **www.tinynerdgames.com/blog**

What do I have to do?

Any answer is highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How you determine what URLs provide what resources depends on your HTTP server and/or server-side code, neither of which you've said anything about in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .htaccess file to truncate your file URL's.

Navigate to your File Manager in cPanel and locate the .htaccess file. Note: you must enable hidden files to view this file.

- Click on Settings at the top right corner
- Select Show hidden files (dotfiles)
- Save new settings

Inside the htaccess file, paste this code;

```
#remove html file extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Now change your link from to https://tinynerdgames.com/blog.html to https://tinynerdgames.com/blog and this should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Using FTP, you would log in to your website, create a directory named `blog`, move the `blog.html` file into the new directory, and rename `blog.html` to `index.html`.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. It says example.com/blog/index.html

Comment: Try using a `/` after blog in your URL: `www.tinynergames.com/blog/`. btw, love the name of your site!